# Why does the song 'Car Wash' appear so often in Eureka?

Tags: plot-explanation, eureka

I've been binge watching the Eureka series (just finished season 4).

So what's the deal with the 'Car Wash' song? It seems that whenever they want to irritate the viewer, they start playing that song. From the time the janitor was singing it in the elevator when he thought he was alone to the psychological stress test on level Q that silly ditty keeps being played.

Does one of the producers own the copyright to that and wants residuals or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an example of the [**Running Gag**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RunningGag) trope.

Unfortunately, in this case, they picked a song you don't like....

Additionally, the song showed up in *Warehouse 13* which indicated that the two shows might exist in the same universe...essentially, an Easter Egg for fans.

In fact, we *know* they share a universe as characters cross over series from time to time.

---

Could they be getting their money's worth having bought the *usage* rights?
 Sure...but that's just plain business-sense.

Comment: They passed the Fargo and Claudia characters back and forth between the two series so I suspect you're correct.